# cannot resize JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a label, added it to a panel, added the panel to an internal frame and the internal frame to a `JFrame`.

`JFrame` uses `FlowLayout`. I am not able to resize the internal frame. I can see the handles to resize but it is not working.

Minimizing or maximizing does not work either unless I am minimizing or maximizing the `JFrame`. Size of `JFrame` is `300, 300`. Not sure what I should be doing.

```
inFrame1=new JInternalFrame("Frame 1",true,true,true,true);
JLabel displayLabel1=new JLabel("This is JInternalFrame #1");
panel1=new JPanel();
panel1.add(displayLabel1);
inFrame1.setVisible(true);
inFrame1.add(panel1);
add(inFrame1);
```

Comment: *and the internal frame to a JFrame.* - an internal frame is designed to be added to a JDesktopPane. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for working examples.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).